# Jenkins git plugin fails on mac os

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a windows machine running jenkins. I have attached a macos node to perform the build task.

On the jenkins job configuration page I added git for scm.

When I start the build job, it starts runnning on the macos instance correctly, but fails with the following:

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: git.exe init
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git.exe"
```

Which is very reasonable, since it is a macos machine. What should I do to get the git plugin run git correctly?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your macos node, I think you have to configure Git in the tools section:

[image]

Maybe you also have to overwrite the PATH environment variable:

[image]

Does it help?

Comment: Yes, it does help, it works as you said. I am amazed that I couldn't find it on my own, although the solution is this simple.